# Logging console error of UI application into AWS

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am new to vue js and front end development. How can I direct the console errors and API errors from front end application that is running on user's browser to cloud watch logs.

I know that in Java backend development, we can use log4j to log the errors to a rolling log file and wire those logs to cloudwatch log groups (so I can monitor cloudwatch logs for any potential errors or warnings). How can I have similar functionality for logging console and API errors from front end vue js application to cloud watch logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a great way to do this from a security standpoint. You'd have to expose your cloudwatch log stream to the world essentially.

You can use npm packages like winston-cloudwatch for this fairly easily, but you have to more or less "hardcode" your credentials since a frontend/vue app runs in the users browser. They'll always be able to see the credentials you're sending along which makes them meaningless.

With that being said, there really isn't any risk of someone doing anything malicious besides sending dirty messages to your logs.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a Lambda endpoint that receives the logs from the vue app and writes them to cloud watch, this way you will be able to log more activities such elements being clicked, or the time each component was shown in the screen.